# Making the top and bottom border of the table visible using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with some rows and columns in html, I want to make just the top and bottom border of the table visible. Can anyone advise on that?

This is my current code:

```
 table#beta
        {
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        table#beta td
        {
            border:1px solid black;
        }

 <table id ="beta" border="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: putting your relevant code/structure is not a crime here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here snippet of code

```
<table>
  <tr><td>hello</td><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>hello</td><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>hello</td><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>hello</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

And style

```
table {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid Black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DDFb9/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this ...

```
<style type="text/css">
.my_table {
    border-top:1px solid ;
    border-bottom:1px solid ;
}
</style>
<table class="my_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Column1</td>
        <td>Column2</td>
        <td>Column3</td>
        <td>Column4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AAAAA</td>
        <td>AAAAA</td>
        <td>AAAAA</td>
        <td>AAAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBBBB</td>
        <td>BBBBB</td>
        <td>BBBBB</td>
        <td>BBBBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
table{
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psXtY/)